# c# How do I cast and pass a generic type parameter to an internal function?

Tags: c#, generics, types, parameters

Imagine I have a "zoo" mobile app. It fetches "Animals" from an online server and stores them in a local database.

```
Class Animal
Class Bird : Animal
Class Fish : Animal
Class Pelican : Bird
Class Penguin : Bird
```

So I create a class GetAnimalsFromServerService that has the following functions.

```
public Task<Animal[]> GetAnimalsFromServer<T>() where T : Animal, new() {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Bird)) {
        return GetBirdsFromServer<T>();
    } else if (typeof (T) == typeof(Fish)){
        return GetFishFromServer<T>();
    }
}


private Task<Bird[]> GetBirdsFromServer<T>() where T : Bird, new() {
    // Bird specific functionality here.
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Pelican)) {
        return _serverConnection.GetPelicansFromServer();
    } else if (typeof (T) == typeof(Penguin)){
        return _serverConnection.GetPenguinsFromServer();
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile because T is of type "Animal" and not Type "Bird" (and GetBirdsFromServer requires type "Bird").

Since after the "if(typeof(T) == typeof(Bird))" check I know that T is of type Bird, is there a way for me to cast T as a Bird?

EDIT:
As requested the line below does not compile

```
return GetBirdsFromServer<T>();
```

The error is:

> The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'GetBirdsFromServer()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to 'Bird'

EDIT 2:
Okay, I think I have an understanding of why this doesn't work. Essentially my original question was "is there a keyword that I don't know about that allows me to do the equivalent of:

```
return GetBirdsFromServer<(T as Bird)>();
```

But this isn't possible because the "as" keyword essentially tells the computer "yo, this object is a bird, trust me". Then if it's not a bird the computer can be like "you lied, I'll just set the object to null then".

But in this case the computer isn't considering an object. So when you lie the computer is like "oh poop, this isn't an object what do i do?". So since the line in isolation doesn't guarantee that T is a Bird, there's no way to do some sort of cast or equivalent.

Comment: Do you have an abstract class somewhere with a type parameter?

Comment: A generic member is pointless if it only works typewise. This is when you have to distinguish between types. In fact the generic member shouldn´t know anything of the possible types that may match the generic constraint. That´s the whole point of a generic constraint. Having said this you shouldn´t use a generic method, but different methods for every possible type instead.

Comment: @HimBromBeere 
I have simplified the functions to make sure the question isn't cluttered. Maybe I have misunderstood your comment, but if "//bird specific functionality here" had a function (e.g. CalculateAviarySpace()). Would it still not be worthwhile using generics?

In addition new "Animal" classes can be added to the zoo. So there might be generic handling of Animals, or generic handling of birds (if they do not match any of the classes).

Comment: If you need to do specific things for each type, generics is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: You are trying to mix two concepts here - generics and inheritance. Not sure if you understand that. Anyway, not good. Forget generics, and concentrate on solving this by using a class hierarchy only.

Comment: The point is, `T` is a type known at *compile-time*. Thus, when you know the time at compile-time, you can also just call another method. There´s no benefit if you use `GetAnimalFromServer<Penguin>` over `GetPenguinFromServer`, is it? You´d have to provide the type anyway. What you want instead is to retrieve an entity from a adatabase without exactly knowing the type at compile-time, obviously. In this case generics are the whrong tool.

Comment: @HimBromBeere
I understand I'm likely misunderstanding something here. But say every time I fetch an animal from the server I also want to do a series of actions (e.g. report the animals I already have to the server so they don't send me duplicates). Wouldn't there be an advantage then? Because otherwise I would have to right the X lines of code in GetPenguinFromServer, GetPelicanFromServer, .... , GetRedPandaFromServer. And every edit of that code would have to be editted many times (for each type of animal in the zoo).

Comment: "I also want to do a series of actions (e.g. report the animals I already have to the server so they don't send me duplicates). Wouldn't there be an advantage then?" Sure, but that´s better done via inheritance, that is you have a single method `Report` that accepts an instance of `Animal`. However you won´t care for the exact type of the `Animal` being passed. So you have `void Report(Animal animal) { Console.WriteLine(animal.Name) }` for instance.

Comment: @HimBromBeere
But don't I now have to do something like `Animal[] storedAnimals = GetAnimalFromPhone<Penguin>(); foreach(Animal a in storedAnimals){ a.Report(); }` At the start of each GetPenguin, GetPelican, .... function I've written (and there could be 100s of animals in the zoo).

Comment: But you have the `Get...FromPhone`-methods anyway, all you do with your generic method is to wrap those 100 different methods. However that wrapper has to do completely different things depending upon the provided generic argument. Generics however assume you´re doing the exact same things for different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this case, you can use reflection, to invoke `GetBirdsFromServer` with needed `T` - "`<(T as Bird)>`". Some another issues(`IsAssignableFrom`, `ContinueWith - Cast` for upcasting) are also fixed:

```
public Task<Animal[]> GetAnimalsFromServer<T>() where T : Animal, new()
{
    if (typeof(Bird).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        var method = GetType().GetMethod(nameof(GetBirdsFromServer));
        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
        var result = generic.Invoke(this, new object[] { });
        return (result as Task<Bird[]>)
                    .ContinueWith(x => x.Result.Cast<Animal>().ToArray());
    }
    //other similar code
}

public Task<Bird[]> GetBirdsFromServer<T>() where T : Bird, new()
{
    // Bird specific functionality here.
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Pelican))        
        return _serverConnection.GetPelicansFromServer()
                    .ContinueWith(x => x.Result.Cast<Bird>().ToArray());        
    //other similar code
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var task = probe.GetAnimalsFromServer<Penguin>();
//type of task.Result.FirstOrDefault() will be Animal
//but actual type will be Penguin
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way around this to make your `GetAnimalsFromServer<T>()` work at compile-time.

The key thing is to create a dictionary of all of the types you want to return and their method to return the types as `Task<Animal[]>`.

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<Task<Animal[]>>> _getFromServer = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Task<Animal[]>>>()
{
    { typeof(Pelican), () => _serverConnection.GetPelicansFromServer().ContinueWith(t => t.Result.Cast<Animal>().ToArray()) },
    { typeof(Penguin), () => _serverConnection.GetPenguinsFromServer().ContinueWith(t => t.Result.Cast<Animal>().ToArray()) },
};
```

Then it becomes pretty straightforward to write your `GetAnimalsFromServer<T>()` method:

```
public Task<Animal[]> GetAnimalsFromServer<T>() where T : Animal, new()
{
    if (_getFromServer.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        return _getFromServer[typeof(T)]();
    }
    return default(Task<Animal[]>);
}
```

I tested this with the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    GetAnimalsFromServer<Pelican>();
    GetAnimalsFromServer<Penguin>();
}

public class Animal { }

public class Bird : Animal { }

public class Pelican : Bird { }

public class Penguin : Bird { }

public static class _serverConnection
{
    public static Task<Pelican[]> GetPelicansFromServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got Pelicans");
        return Task.Run(() => new Pelican[] { });
    }
    public static Task<Penguin[]> GetPenguinsFromServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got Penguins");
        return Task.Run(() => new Penguin[] { });
    }
}
```

When I run it I get the following on the console:

```
Got Pelicans
Got Penguins
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying:

```
return GetBirdsFromServer<T>();
```

You basically say that you need to get the birds from server of type `Animal`. But you defined T in `GetBirdsFromServer` as a class which inherits `Bird`. What you did with that return is something like Animal (T) inherits from Bird.

What you need to do is to make some kind of strategy/factory to get you the kind of response you want. For example:

```
return GetBirdsFromServer<Pelican>();
```

Another thing that it's worth mentioning, it's that in this case it seems like generics are a little too much (over design). Simple inheritance with polymorphism  should be enough.